# Responsive nested rows bootstrap

Tags: html, css, nested, rows

Haii, I wrote the following code using bootstrap:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ROOD" >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 image GEEL" >
               <img src="images/camera.png" class="home">
               <h4>Vraag uw foto digitaal op!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 image GROEN">
               <img src="images/card.png" class="home">
               <h4>Probeer het proeflidmaatschap!</h4>
            </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 nieuws PAARS">
       <h1>..</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Which should result in this on mobile devices:
[phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N1X3.png)

But the two nested rows keep being put on top of each other, whereas they should be placed next to each other on mobile phones. Like this:
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wbOe.png)
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've got a typo. there's no class `col-sx-12` in bootstrap. it called `col-xs-12`. the same with `col-xs-6`

Comment: Agree with Banzay - also, there's a missing closing `</div>` in the code you shared - not sure if that's an issue or you just missed it when pasting this in.

Comment: Fixed the typo, still got the same problem

Comment: The div is missing because of pasting the code here

Comment: Should red stripes be on both sides?

Comment: Your code seems working well... Are you in the right media query?

Comment: Does not really matter, as long as the two nested rows are placed next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copy the HTML below to begin working with a minimal Bootstrap document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

#### The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags

Than you need to link bootstrap in you html code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>...</body>
```

Next you can paste html code from snippet into the body.

```css
.ROOD {
  background: red;
}
.GEEL {
  background: yellow;
}
.GROEN {
  background: green;
}
.PAARS {
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ROOD" >
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 image GEEL" >
      <img src="images/camera.png" class="home">
      <h4>Vraag uw foto digitaal op!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 image GROEN">
      <img src="images/card.png" class="home">
      <h4>Probeer het proeflidmaatschap!</h4>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 nieuws PAARS">
    <h1>..</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works if I run the snippet in here, however, when I copy paste this into my final html file, it does not work anymore. That's very interesting. Could it be due to other html or css code that I've written?

Comment: I've changed the answer. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem. I included the bootstrap css file before my own css file, which does not work. When I do it the other way around it does. However, I need my own css to overwrite some styles of bootstrap.. How should I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I have found my mistake! Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Congratulations! :)